# Is it possible for an application to have a security hole that a malware can exploit?

Tags: android, security, malware

I'm currently doing a research on the different Android malwares and how they can affect an application. However, my research shows that Android malwares are distributed either via repackaged counterfeit applications or original applications with hidden malware.

- If this is so, does it mean that your device can only be infected if you downloaded an already infected application? Or is it possible for a legitimate application that is already installed in the device to get infected?
- Is there an existing malware that can infect an already installed application? What is it?
- How do malwares infect an already installed application?
- What are the different possible security holes in an application that a malware can exploit?
- How do you protect an application against malwares? What are the safety measures in coding to avoid malware exploit?

Please be rest assured that I have no intention to create a malware. I'm asking these questions to know if there is any way in code that I can protect my application against malwares. I'm developing a mobile banking application so the security of the application is crucial.

Comment: This question is really not a programming question.  It may be better suited for http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you asking whether it's possible for an Android application to have its own security hole?

Comment: @bdares: It is a programming question because what I want to know is how malwares attack an application via code.

Comment: @SLaks: Yes. I'm asking if it's possible for an Android application to have a security hole that a malware can exploit. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @SLaks: I updated my question to make it more clear. :) Thanks, again!

Comment: I don't believe this is possible for an application to "have" a security loop hole that exposes itself.  If an application accepts user input, yes input can be invalid, but the code can't be overwritten from the input. The worst that will happen is the application will crash because the input throws an exception.  However, on rooted devices or apps that take advantage of rare OS exploits(which may not exist, would have to search), the data for another app can be overwritten and code can be injected.  It would be fairly easy to do on a rooted device because it allows access to sensitive files.

Comment: @user1132959: SQL injection? Code compilation? XSS in WebViews?

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**: I am in no way a security expert, so take my words with a grain (or a pound) of salt.

It is possible for a malware to infect other apps on rooted phones. If the malware manages to convince the user to give it superuser rights (which is not that hard), the malware can do several things that would allow it to "inject" its own malicious code in other applications, in which case every time the infected application is run, it can infect other apps as well.

In the case of a non-rooted phone, it is harder for a malware to inject its own code. If there is an app that has a service that reads dex code from an Intent bundle and stores it in its local directory and then uses ClassLoader to load and execute that code, a malware would be able to inject malicious code, provided the target app does not require any permissions and allows anyone to send such an intent. However, the chances of finding an application like that are quite slim.

Note that the protection of the application against malware is in most cases function of the OS, not the application itself. If the OS lets any third party app do whatever it wants, there's nothing your app can do to protect itself (baring switching from a client app to a web app, and even then it's possible albeit harder to inject malicious JS in the browser). Hence, you can't protect yourself on rooted phones. And on non-rooted phones the OS already does quite good isolation, so unless you blindly trust external input and treat it as executable code, there's not much you really need to do to protect yourself.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply! My concern is also on rooted phones since a malware with SU privilege can easily manipulate the infected device. Is there any first line of defense than an application can do for malwares that spies on its transaction? (like those that can read data packets if there is any. also consdering that the transaction is already made in https)

Comment: Also, I would just to clarify this: "It is possible for a malware to infect other apps on rooted phones" Did you mean that it is possible for an Android malware to attach itself to an installed application without the need of repackaging the app? Or does the malware simply listens to the activity of the application?

Comment: @Arci a malware on rooted phone can modify the executable code of an application (app can defend by attempting to verify the signature of its .apk), or it can modify system libraries that the application relies on (framework.jar for example).

Comment: Thanks again! If a malware can modify the executable code of an app, then the malware can also go away by modifying the code so the app won't verify its signature. :|

Comment: Yep. :-) Than again, these are usually very targeted attacks.

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine that a malware may be able to hack the android-os to replace one banking Form(Activity) "Enter pin" with its own via a hacked intend mechanism. The android-intent-mechanism controlls which Forms(Activities) are opend.

So there would be no need to modify your banking-app at all to compromise the banking customer. But this is only hypothetical.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I can imagine that such malware can only be made if it targets a specific application. But if such malware exists, I don't think there's anything I can still do to protect my app. Do you know any malware that targets bank specific application?